# Quicksort Recursion - StackOverFlow

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, quicksort, partitioning

I'm implementing a recursive quicksort however I'm receiving stackoverflow and not sure where the bug lies :(

I'm sorting 1 million ints from 10-50.

I works for sizes less than 1 million like 100 thousand etc.

```
public Quicksort(int NUM_TESTS, int NUM_ELEMENTS){
    num_tests = NUM_TESTS;
    num_elements = NUM_ELEMENTS;
}

private void start(){
    for (int i = 0; i < num_tests; i++){
        int[] d1 = dataGeneration(num_elements);
        qSortRecursive(d1,0,d1.length-1);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    Quicksort q = new Quicksort(1,1000000);
    q.start();    
}

private int[] dataGeneration(int n) {
    int[] d1 = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        d1[i] = (int)(Math.random() * ((50 - 10) + 1) + 10);
    }
    return d1;
}

private void qSortRecursive(int[] data, int left, int right){
    if(left < right){
        int pivot = partition(data,left,right);
        qSortRecursive(data,left,pivot-1);
        qSortRecursive(data,pivot+1,right);
    }
}

private int partition(int[] data, int left, int right){
    int pivot = left ;
    left++;
    while (left <= right){
        while (left <= right && data[left] <= data[pivot]) {
            left++;
        }

        while (left <= right && data[right] >= data[pivot]){
            right--;
        }

        if (left < right){
            swap(data,left,right);
            left++;
            right--;
        }          
    }

    if (data[right] <= data[pivot]){
        if (data[right] != data[pivot]){
            swap(data,right,pivot);
        }
        pivot = right;
    } 

    return pivot;
}

private void swap(int[] data, int i, int j){
    int temp = data[i];
    data[i] = data[j];
    data[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the limitations of recursion? They're important to understand if you're using it. Unless you can guarantee that the function will be Tail Call optimized, it will always fail eventually with a StackOverflow.

Comment: As in extensive overhead etc?

Comment: Unoptimized recursion will continue to consume stack frames every time it recurses. Once you've taken up more space than the stack can hold, it "overflows". There's little you can do, especially in a language like Java. If you require it to process millions of elements, you'll need to switch to an iterative algorithm, or switch to another language that supports TCO. Java isn't a great language to use recursion in.

Comment: Yea well my assignment requires I do both recursive and iterative up to 1m elements so hmm

Comment: You can increase your stack size, but unless the teacher does the same when they test it, they'll get a StackOverflow when they run it. I'd hope that if your teacher is asking you to do this, they'd know the stack may be too small for this to work. Lookup how to increase stack size. I can't remember the command off the top of my head.

Comment: I have a look, i dont think there is anything wrong with the code itself, I try and figure somethin out

Comment: I would take a look at [*optimizations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Optimizations) on the Quicksort Wikipedia page. And you can't do the first (because Java doesn't have tail calls). You could always ask your teacher.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void qSortRecursive(int[] data, int left, int right){
    while (left < right){
        int pivot = partition(data,left,right);
        if (pivot - left < right - pivot){
            qSortRecursive(data, left, pivot - 1);
            left = pivot + 1;
        } else {
            qSortRecursive(data, pivot + 1, right);
            right = pivot - 1;
        }
    }
```

Performing a tail call by reducing number of recursion solved my problem, thanks for help everyone :)

Comment: This is not even remotely a tail call. A tail call means that the 'current' stack frame can be replaced by the 'next' stack frame, because control will never need to return to the 'current' stack frame. Here, control must return to the 'current' stack frame in order to execute the `left =` or `right =`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to rewrite the algorithm without recursion. Well, you remove recursion by adding your own stack and in that case you can have available the entire memory, not just size of stack.

Something like: http://alienryderflex.com/quicksort/